# Python, Command Line, Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, windows-7

NEW Edit. I am using Python2.7.5 in Windows 7. I'm new to command line arguments. I am trying to do this exercise:

Write a program that reads in a string on the command line and returns a table of the letters which occur in the string with the number of times each letter occurs. For example:

```
 $ python letter_counts.py "ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters."
 a  2
 c  1
 d  1
 # etc.
```

I have some fundamental problems: How do I add strings to the command line?

I went to Control Panel and altered the Path (adding ;C:\Python27)

Now I'm in cmd.exe

This gets the right answer

```
 >>>python
 Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
```

However these get SyntaxError: invalid syntax:

```
 python letter_counts.py
 C:\Python27\python.exe
 C:\Python27\pythonw.exe  
 C:\Python27\python.exe .\letter_counts.py
```

Any suggestions? thank you!

Comment: The python interpreter is not a shell. Use cmd.exe.

Comment: How can I use/access cmd.exe ?

Comment: Windows Key + R, type 'cmd' (without quotes) hit enter.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying your path, did you start up a new instance of the command prompt (this has caused me much grief in the past)?  To check if your path change was successful:

```
echo %PATH%
```

and check to see if C:\Python2.7.5 was appended to it.

If not then run:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python2.7.5
```

To call a python script with a command line argument (assuming that your script is in the current working directory):

```
python letter_counts.py "Your Text Goes Here"
```

OR if you just want to be overly verbose (or your PATH still isn't right):

```
C:\Python2.7.5\python.exe .\letter_counts.py "Your text still goes here"
```

**EDIT**:
Make sure you are doing this from the command prompt and *not* the python interpreter.  To access the command prompt you can hit:

```
1. Windows Key + R
2. type "cmd" (without quotes) and hit enter
```

Comment: Hi, I have  ;C:\Python2.7.5) appended to Path. In cmd.exe: when I type python, I get the right response (Python 2.7.5 etc.. ) however when I type python letter_counts.py "text" I get "invalid syntax". Any suggestions?

Comment: Wait... I know what's happening: When you type in just "python" it takes you into the interactive interpreter... this is **NOT** what you want.  If you see ">>" before your cursor then type in quit() to fall back into the cmd shell.  Now you can type in "python letter_counts.py 'text'".

Comment: @user2547317: Moral of story: running python alone will take you away from the safe confines of the cmd shell and place you into the "interactive interpreter"  (hence the ">>") where you will have to use quit() to escape from.  Instead, 'python filename.py various_args_here' will make python execute your script and will return you to the cmd prompt.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have familiarized myself with the windows command prompt.. it's working. However: I still need to do this exercise in python. That would allow me to loop thru and count the command line arguments. How would I do this in Python? If I have a file letter_counts.py  : how do I add these command line arguments and loop thru them in Python "ThiS is String with Upper and lower case Letters."  ?

Answer (score 0):

In response to your question on 'adding strings to the command line'.

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

will give you the command line args you passed in. In your case, it looks like you want the first argument, so you would do something like:

```
print sys.argv[1]
```

note that sys.argv[0] will give you the filename you passed into python, so you actually want [1] in this case.

I don't use Windows, but if you want an easy setup python environment you could look into ActivePython perhaps. Worst case or as a temporary solution you could just go to the folder where python.exe is located and run your scripts there.